# How secure is Ciphersweet?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hmac

> For anybody interested in some really good answers. I later asked this question on security.stackexchange.com: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196833/how-secure-is-the-ciphersweet-library-for-searchable-encryption-and-why-is-a-du

I'm currently managing a code base in which we've got a mysql database with all records encrypted using the [php-encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/classes/Crypto.md). This works well for our current setup. We now got a new business requirement that should make it possible to do a SELECT based on one of the encrypted fields.

Since it is impossible to select based on the encrypted values I searched around and found [ciphersweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet). It's a new (6 months old) repo with currently only 136 github stars. I've read through a [blogpost about it](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) written by the company behind the lib. It sounds ok, but since I'm not a cryptographic expert I can't really judge it's secureness.

Is there anybody else out there who can comment on this library/technology? or does anybody know another source where the quality of this technology is evaluated?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this lib, but the company authored https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat which is the de facto standard.

It is even mentioned on https://php.net/random_bytes

> Note: Although this function was added to PHP in PHP 7.0, a » userland implementation is available for PHP 5.2 to 5.